# A function that can only be called once

Tags: javascript, validation, dom, event-listener

So I've run into an issue where an image will be created over and over again if I keep focusing out of the textbox, I just want the picture to be created one time and if I decide to click in the textbox and focus away from it, I don't want more images to be created so just a one and done type of function. I tried experimenting with remove EventListener but that didn't really do anything for me.

```js
function validateData(validationType) {
  var alpha = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

  if (validationType === "firstname") {
    var firstName = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0];
    if (firstName.value.match(alpha)) {
      alert("Yes");
    } else {
      alert("No");
      image();
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function creator() {
  document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].addEventListener('blur', () => validateData("firstname"));
}


function image() {
  var imgx = document.createElement("img");
  imgx.src = "https://i.imgur.com/pwLBEus.jpg";
  document.getElementById("imgsauce").appendChild(imgx);
  document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].addEventListener('blur', image);
  document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].removeEventListener('blur', image);
}
```

```html
<h2>The Element</h2>
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="input">
<div id="imgsauce"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can set a helper variable which is set when the image() function was called (var alreadyCalled). And only if the helper variable isn't true, then call the append function otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `once` option of [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].addEventListener('blur', image, {
  once: true
});

function image() {
  console.log('once');
  var imgx = document.createElement("img");
  imgx.src = "https://i.imgur.com/pwLBEus.jpg";
  document.getElementById("imgsauce").appendChild(imgx);
}
```

```html
<h2>The Element</h2>
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="input">
<div id="imgsauce"></div>
```

Comment: Only thing to note is that [the `once` option is not supported by IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=once).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

The problem you have now is because of a nuance with `removeEventListener`. It can only remove a function as a listener if you pass that function again: meaning you can never use this function to remove an anonymous function. And you've added an anonymous function. To make this simpler, I would make things into one single function that references itself when it is time to be removed.

```js
document.querySelector('#namesauce').addEventListener('blur', listener);

function listener(event) {
  const validationType = event.target.name;
  if (validationType === "firstname") {
    if (/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(event.target.value)) {
      console.log('Yes');
    } else {
      console.log('No');
      const imgx = document.createElement('img');
      imgx.src = "https://i.imgur.com/pwLBEus.jpg";
      document.querySelector('#imgsauce').appendChild(imgx);

      document.querySelector('#namesauce').removeEventListener('blur', listener);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>The Element</h2>
<input id="namesauce" type="text" name="firstname" class="input">
<div id="imgsauce"></div>
```

---

**Original Answer:**

```js
window.onload = function creator() {
  document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].addEventListener('blur', image, removeImage);
}
```

I'm not sure what you're doing by passing `removeImage` into `addEventListener`, but it won't do anything. Instead, make the function you're passing as the listener (`image`) also remove itself. So something like:

```js
window.onload = function creator() {
  document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].addEventListener('blur', image);
}

function image() {
  var imgx = document.createElement("img");
  imgx.src = "https://i.imgur.com/pwLBEus.jpg";
  document.getElementById("imgsauce").appendChild(imgx);
  document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].removeEventListener('blur', image);
}
```

```html
<h2>The Element</h2>
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="input">
<div id="imgsauce"></div>
```

Comment: Hi I updated my code so now the picture will only show if it doesn't meet the conditions of the if statement. But I still have the issue of the picture showing multiple times, I am not really sure how to make this work correctly now that it is inside an if else statement.

Comment: @EIRIKDAAE See my updated answer. Does that help? Alternatively, in the event listener, you could just do a quick, `if (/* image is child of imgsauce */) { // ... }` ...

Comment: Hey so I also want to create an image for when the conditions are met so what would be the best way to go about that. I tried just copying and pasting the code for both the if and else conditions but with different image sources but because that removes the eventlistener so I can only use it once instead. Is there any way for the function to only run once (creates one image no matter the about of times you focus out) but keeps the eventlistener so I can just replace the current image with a different image once the other condition has been met?

Comment: See my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59098374/10549827).

Answer (score 0):

Since your new question (on the comment to my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59095380/10549827)) has such a different implementation, I'm going to put it as a separate answer.

If all you wish to do is to display a different image based on success or failure, it's way simpler to do. You no longer have to worry about removing the listener, so you can use an anonymous function. Now, it is a just a matter of thinking of the problem differently.

Instead of creating a new image if the answer fails vs. succeeds, just put one in the DOM and hide it — you're going to show it no matter what anyways. Then you just have to throw a little CSS in there (optional, just to keep the DOM tidy).

```js
document.querySelector('#namesauce').addEventListener('blur', event => {
  const validationType = event.target.name;
  if (validationType === 'firstname') {
    let src = "";
    if (/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(event.target.value)) {
      console.log('Yes!');
      src = "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png?text=Yes"
    } else {
      console.log('No!');
      src = "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png?text=No"
    }

    const imgx = document.querySelector('#result-img');

    // classList.remove does nothing if the class is not found
    imgx.src = src;
    imgx.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>The Element</h2>
<input id="namesauce" type="text" name="firstname" class="input">
<div id="imgsauce">
  <img id="result-img" src="" alt="" class="hidden">
</div>
```

P.S., if you don't want a big error message when the `<input>` is left empty, just throw a

```js
if (event.target.value.length > 0) {
  // ...
}
```

in there somewhere.